# How to restrict access to the outer Lambda method from the inner Lambda when using the Lambda of the Kotlin extension function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am imitating LazyDsl in Jetpack Compose to implement a custom Preference layout.

This is my code:

[`Preference.kt`](https://github.com/xfqwdsj/EasyTest-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/xyz/xfqlittlefan/easytest/widget/Preference.kt)

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PreferenceContainer(
    /* ... */,
    content: PreferenceScope.() -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn(
        /* ... */,
        content = PreferenceScope(context).apply(content).getLazyListScope()
    )
}

class PreferenceScope(private val context: Context) {
    private val itemList = mutableListOf<@Composable () -> Unit>()

    fun getLazyListScope(): LazyListScope.() -> Unit = {
        items(itemList) { it() }
    }

    fun category(title: String, items: PreferenceCategoryScope.() -> Unit) {
        /* ... */
    }
}

class PreferenceCategoryScope(private val itemList: MutableList<@Composable () -> Unit>, context: Context) {
    private val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

    fun editPreference( /* ... */ ) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

It can be called like this:

[`SettingsActivity.kt`](https://github.com/xfqwdsj/EasyTest-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/xyz/xfqlittlefan/easytest/activity/SettingsActivity.kt)

```kotlin
PreferenceContainer( /* ... */ ) {
    category( /* ... */ ) {
        editPreference( /* ... */ )
    }
}
```

But it can also be used like this:

```kotlin
PreferenceContainer( /* ... */ ) {
    category( /* ... */ ) {
        category( /* ... */ ) { }  //This is not what I want: category() is called in category()
    }
}
```

Therefore, the problem can be embodied as: how to make `category()` unable to be called by the Lambda parameter in `category()`. If anyone knows, I would be very grateful, thank you!

Comment: See [@DslMarker](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html#scope-control-dslmarker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reminding me in the comments, I found the answer.

The code can be modified like this:

```kotlin
@DslMarker
annotation class PreferenceDsl

@Composable
fun PreferenceContainer(
    /* ... */,
    content: PreferenceScope.() -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn(
        /* ... */,
        content = PreferenceScope(context).apply(content).getLazyListScope()
    )
}

@PreferenceDsl
class PreferenceScope(private val context: Context) {
    private val itemList = mutableListOf<@Composable () -> Unit>()

    fun getLazyListScope(): LazyListScope.() -> Unit = {
        items(itemList) { it() }
    }

    fun category(title: String, items: PreferenceCategoryScope.() -> Unit) {
        /* ... */
    }
}

@PreferenceDsl
class PreferenceCategoryScope(private val itemList: MutableList<@Composable () -> Unit>, context: Context) {
    private val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

    fun editPreference( /* ... */ ) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```